# Kafka Tombstone messages are not deleted

Tags: apache-kafka

This topic is basically about the observation that delete marker records (tombstones) are not deleted as expected.

I have the following initial situation (using **Kafka 2.6**)

```
1 topic with 1 partition
Offsets: Partition: 0; low: 2; high: 947; offset: 947; #(high-low): 945
Number of not null records: 5
Number of all records     : 270
```

Topic configuration is this:

```
cleanup.polic=compact
min.compaction.lag.ms=3600000
min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.5
segment.ms=3600000
delete.retention.ms=86400000
```

The log files of this partition are

```
43029 Nov 21 20:55 00000000000000000000.log
  326 Nov 22 12:14 00000000000000000937.log
  772 Nov 24 15:11 00000000000000000939.log
  561 Nov 24 16:17 00000000000000000941.log
  174 Nov 24 17:17 00000000000000000943.log
  772 Dec 17 11:38 00000000000000000944.log
  174 Dec 17 12:38 00000000000000000946.log
```

The oldest record (tombstone) is from 2021-06-21. The last offsets are (distinguished between tombstone and data record):

```
936 tombstone (delete marker)
937 tombstone (delete marker)
938 tombstone (delete marker)
939 data
940 data
941 tombstone (delete marker)
942 data
943 tombstone (delete marker)
944 data
945 data
946 tombstone (delete marker) 2021-12-17
```

All older records are tombstone records. So, there is a huge amount of tombstone records that are not deleted although delete.retention.ms is one day. The *000.log and *937.log files include only tombstones and also the timestamps of these files are very old.

My questions is, why are the old tombstones not deleted? Trying to find an answer to this questions lead to the blog post “[Kafka quirks: tombstones that refuse to disappear](https://www.javierholguera.com/2020/02/17/kafka-quirks-tombstones-that-refuse-to-disappear/)” and Kafka Issue [KAFKA-8522](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8522).

But I am not sure if my observation fits to the post and issue. Espacially changing delete.retention.ms to ‘0’ did not change anything on my system.

Any explanation is really welcome. Hints to overcome this situation even more as we have topics with high throughput and lots of tombstone message which seem to gather at the beginning of the log.

Thanks and kind regards

Franz

Comment: Oh, sorry. That is a local format. I will remove that.

Comment: Based on the very small difference in the number of the logs names, I have a feeling you're missing some details about how `min.cleanable.dirty.ratio` is calculated or used.

Comment: Either that, or setting the retention setting lower doesn't retroactively start deleting things; the log cleaner thread will still need invoked by generating new data to get compacted. You could also upgrade your cluster since it seems the jira you linked to is fixed now